# Parsing an html table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

To start off here's my current code in its entirety:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import sgmllib
import re

page = 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/\
8177/000114036111018563/form10k.htm'

sock = urllib.urlopen(page)
raw = sock.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw)

tablelist = soup.findAll('table')

class MyParser(sgmllib.SGMLParser):

def parse(self, segment):
    self.feed(segment)
    self.close()

def __init__(self, verbose=0):
    sgmllib.SGMLParser.__init__(self, verbose)
    self.descriptions = []
    self.inside_td_element = 0
    self.starting_description = 0

def start_td(self, attributes):
    for name, value in attributes:
        if name == "valign":
            self.inside_td_element = 1
            self.starting_description = 1
        else:
            self.inside_td_element = 1
            self.starting_description = 1

def end_td(self):
    self.inside_td_element = 0

def handle_data(self, data):
    if self.inside_td_element:
        if self.starting_description:
            self.descriptions.append(data)
            self.starting_description = 0
        else:
            self.descriptions[-1] += data

def get_descriptions(self):
    return self.descriptions

counter = 0
trlist = []
dtablelist = []

while counter < len(tablelist):
    trsegment = tablelist[counter].findAll('tr')
    trlist.append(trsegment)
    strsegment = str(trsegment)
    myparser = MyParser()
    myparser.parse(strsegment)
    sub = myparser.get_descriptions()
    dtablelist.append(sub)
    counter = counter + 1

ex = []

dtablelist = [s for s in dtablelist if s != ex]
```

So what I want to accomplish is take all the tables from an html document, then reprint them onto an Excel spreadsheet. So when I create trlist the output looks like this:

```
print trlist[1]
[<tr>
<td valign="top" width="25%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-    SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; TEXT-DECORATION: underline">&#160;</font></td>
<td valign="top" width="25%">
<div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; TEXT-DECORATION: underline">Title of each class</font></div>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="25%" style="TEXT-ALIGN: center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; TEXT-DECORATION: underline">Name of exchange</font></td>
<td valign="top" width="25%" style="TEXT-ALIGN: center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman; TEXT-DECORATION: underline">&#160;</font></td>
</tr>, <tr>
<td valign="top" width="25%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman">&#160;</font></td>
<td valign="top" width="25%">
<div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Common Stock, par value</font>    </font></div>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="25%">
<div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="center">
<div style="DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-LEFT: 0pt; TEXT-INDENT: 0pt; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0pt" align="center"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman"><font style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold"><font style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold"><     <font style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold">NASDAQ Global Market</font></font></font></font></div>
</div>
</td>
<td valign="top" width="25%"><font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: times new roman">&#160;</font></td>
</tr>,...
```

As you can see each item in trlist is each individual row ( . . . ) of the table which is what I want. But when I run each trlist item through my sgmllib parser to retrieve the contents between the tags I get this output:

```
print dtablelist[1]
['\nTitle of each class\n', 'Name of exchange', '\nCommon Stock, par value\n', '\n\nNASDAQ Global Market\n\n', '\n$1.00 per share\n']
```

As you can see, the output is each of the contents as their own individual string, instead of a list of the contents of each table row (). So essentially I want the output:

```
[['\nTitle of each class\n', 'Name of exchange'], ['\nCommon Stock, par value\n', '\n\nNASDAQ Global Market\n\n'], ['\n$1.00 per share\n']]
```

Is it because I have to turn trlist into a string before I parse it with MyParser? Does anyone know any way around this, allowing me to parse lists within lists (aka Inception shit)?

Comment: Why are you using two different parsers instead of just using BeautifulSoup for the whole thing? (And why are you importing BeautifulSoup twice?)

Comment: The importing BeautifulSoup twice was a mistake.  Also I am using sgmllib to parse the <tr> because when I do: trsegment = tablelist[counter].findAll('tr').  This returns a list type output instead of a Tag or BeautifulSoup type output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/index.html):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> data = ["<tr><td>test</td><td>help</td></tr>", "<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>"]
>>> [lxml.html.fromstring(tr).xpath(".//text()") for tr in data]
[['test', 'help'], ['data1', 'data2']]
```

And here is some more complete code. It stores the text in a list containing a list of tables, and each table has a list of tr's, and each tr has a list of all the text.

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

data = urllib.urlopen('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/8177/000114036111018563/form10k.htm').read()
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

tables = []
for tbl in tree.iterfind('.//table'):
    tele = []
    tables.append(tele)
    for tr in tbl.iterfind('.//tr'):
        text = [e.strip() for e in tr.xpath('.//text()') if len(e.strip()) > 0]
        tele.append(text)

print tables
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is searching for a solution of the same problem but is using python 3:

You don't have to use an external library for parsing an HTML table even if you are using python 3. There the `SGMLParser` class was replaced by `HTMLParser` from `html.parser`. I've written code for a simple derived `HTMLParser` class. It is [here in a github repo](https://github.com/schmijos/html-table-parser-python3/blob/master/html_table_parser/parser.py). It simply does remember the current scope of a `<td>`, `<tr>` or `<table>` tag. The advantages over using *etree* are that it runs correctly on non-xml-compliant html and that it doesn't use external libraries.

You can use that class (here named `HTMLTableParser`) the following way:

```
import urllib.request
from html_table_parser import HTMLTableParser

target = 'http://www.twitter.com'

# get website content
req = urllib.request.Request(url=target)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
xhtml = f.read().decode('utf-8')

# instantiate the parser and feed it
p = HTMLTableParser()
p.feed(xhtml)
print(p.tables)
```

The output of this is a list of 2D-lists representing tables. It looks maybe like this:

```
[[['   ', ' Anmelden ']],
 [['Land', 'Code', 'Für Kunden von'],
  ['Vereinigte Staaten', '40404', '(beliebig)'],
  ['Kanada', '21212', '(beliebig)'],
  ...
  ['3424486444', 'Vodafone'],
  ['  Zeige SMS-Kurzwahlen für andere Länder ']]]
```